# Mac Server (Snow Leopard) NIC Redundancy on Separate Switches

Tags: redundancy, osx-snow-leopard

I have a Mac Snow Leopard Server with 2 NIC's.  Each NIC is plugged into a separate physical switch.  Currently each NIC has it's own IP, but I would like to setup redundancy so that they communicate with one combined IP.  I am unsure how to do this on a Mac Server.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up an LACP aggregate between the two if they are on the SAME switch.  Pages 166-167 of:

[10.6 Advanced Server Admin Guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=answerlink&url=http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/ServerAdmin_v10.6.pdf&answerid=16777216&src=support_site.manuals.search)

I know of no Teaming software available to allow failover across switches.  It's another missing enterprise feature.

Comment: I think you may also have to set the team on the switch side for OS X to be able to use it.

Comment: They are not on the same switch because it is not possible in our infrastructure (without losing redundancy), but I have heard you can write a script to accomplish the task.

Comment: Setting up and LACP (802.3ad aggregate) requires a port channel on the switch yes.

Comment: You can certainly control bonding from the command like [man networksetup](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html).  But if what Tatas, says is true, and the bonding cannot work across a switch, then you may be SOL.  A simple script cannot make the kernel do anything that it is not designed to do.

Comment: Unless you're using some sort of virtualized technology with your switches, you can't do this.  You can't port channel across switches, they don't share mac address tables.